# FancyBox issue with images and achors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I want to have images in FancyBox without margin. However setting options in JS doesn't work.

```
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    margin: [0, 0]
    gutter: 0
});
```

I've noticed that is because a part of anchor elements which encapsulate images are outside of those images. You can see a demo here:

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1u1dnjgq/)

When you hover between two images near a bottom you can see a 'pointer' cursor.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not so much a matter of javascript, but of styling:**

You have inline elements (images) within inline elements (anchors), just like some bold text inside some italic text (just worse, since your images have a lot of height...).

If you draw a border around the anchors, you see how that is bad. The browser tries to put the images "on the line". Images stick somewhat unhealthy out:
[image]

And: In "inline mode" all whitespace matters (so you'd need to make your tags `...><...` to avoid that. Making your html very ugly. Inline-Block would already be a little bit better, but still spaces:

[image]

( you could set `font-size: 0` on the outer wrap, but that would be an ugly hack of removing those spaces...)

**Better solution**

settle for block & float:

[image]

The `display:block` on the image prevents that the inner whitespace counts (remove, to figure out). Don't forget to clearfloat the wrapping div.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I wont' recommend using a directly, instead use a class and add it to the anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your boxes in a div and set `font-size: 0` style on it. This [link](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) can be helpful as well.

```js
$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
  margin: [0, 0]
  gutter: 0
});
```

```css
#fancy {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fancy">
<a href="http://placehold.it/500x500" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</a><a href="http://placehold.it/500x500" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</a><a href="http://placehold.it/500x500" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</a><a href="http://placehold.it/500x500" data-fancybox data-caption="My caption">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see a margin and why do think that visual presentation of your links has any connection with fancyBox?

If you mean the space between your links, then the simplest method would be to:

```
a {
  float: left;
}

a img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1u1dnjgq/3/

Comment: Doesn't work - there is still whitespace between two rows. Also - I would like to stay away from floats

Comment: There is nothing wrong using floats. Space between rows is due to vertical alignment of images, see updated demo.